# Audio in Background in iphone

Tags: iphone, audio

I want to make an app which can play audio in background in iphone.Is there any tutorial or example available?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty out there! Google is your friend :)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW1